# copy using PHP exec command and scp

Tags: php, linux, scp

I want to copy a zip file from remote to my local system using SCP.
I have a php file where i use php function exec();
if i run upload.php like http://www.abc.com/upload.php.
The zip file should copy to my local linux folder my path is 
/var/www/html/mydirectory/
How can i do this ?

Comment: This isn't very clear (to me, at least).  Perhaps if you posted what you have so far, and highlight where your doubts lie, that would help?

Comment: You want to upload a file via web form using php, then after it is uploaded via a browser, scp it to another host ?  Is that what you are asking ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP's [PECL ssh2 extension](http://pecl.php.net/ssh2) that provides [ssh2_scp_send](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php).

Answer (score 0):

In order to automate any ssh connection like scp you have to set up a pair of auth keys.

This will allow your remote computer to connect to your local computer with out a password prompt.  A simple google search will show you how to set this up.  The resource I used is http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html.

The auth key allow the computers to recognize each other and handshake with out a user prompt but remember doing this does provide free ssh access from your remote location to your home computer without a password, so handle permissions carefully.

A better way than an scp if you don't need encryption is to set up a wget on your local computer to grab off your remote computer's web dir.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems like you are asking how to download a zip file from your remote web server. In that case, you could simply give the browser the direct path to the zip and let it download it. You can't *push* a file from the server to the local machine with SCP.  Use HTTPS if you're concerned about security. If the zip file is outside of the web directory, you can use PHP to read the file (assuming apache has access to it) and then output it to the browser.